# Nhibernate: readonly property causes eager load

Tags: nhibernate

We've recently upgraded to the latest version of NHibernate (3.3.3.4001) and I've run into an issue that did not exist in NHibernate 2.1.2.4000. This leads me to believe it may be an issue with the new built-in bytecode provider.

Consider the following mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Foo.Core.Domain" assembly="Foo.Core" default-access="property">
  <class name="EntityA" table="EntityA" lazy="true">

    <id name="Id" column="EntityAId">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="EntityB" column="EntityBId" class="EntityB" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="EntityC" column="EntityCId" class="EntityC" not-null="true" access="readonly" insert="true" update="false" />


  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Foo.Core.Domain" assembly="Foo.Core" default-access="property">
  <class name="EntityB" table="EntityB" lazy="true">

    <id name="Id" column="EntityBId">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="EntityC" column="EntityCId" class="EntityC" not-null="true"  />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Foo.Core.Domain" assembly="Foo.Core" default-access="property">
  <class name="EntityC" table="EntityC" lazy="true">

    <id name="Id" column="EntityCId">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>


  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my class definition for EntityA:

```
Public Class EntityA

    Public Overridable Property Id As Integer

    Public Overridable Property EntityB As EntityB

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property EntityC As EntityC
        Get
           Return If(EntityB IsNot Nothing, EntityB.EntityC, Nothing)
        End Get
    End Property


End Class
```

The issue exists when I call Session.Get for an instance of EntityA - it immediately causes a select to be issued for its corresponding EntityB as well:

```
Session.Get(Of EntityA)(id) ' Causes the EntityB that EntityA references to be loaded as well.
```

My best guess is that the bytecode provider is causing my readonly "EntityC" property to be evaluated when the proxy is built, which forces the load of the referenced EntityB.

Is there any way to avoid the eager load from occuring using this type of a model with NHibernate 3.3.3?

Comment: Sorry if stupid comment but, according to EntityA.EntityC property code, I don't see the point of EntityA.EntityC being in the mapping (didn't know you could define explicit readonly property in VB.Net whereas, AFAIK, you can not in C#)

Comment: To be clear, there is a point behind this in my actual implementation (this is just a contrived example to illustrate the issue) - I need the column to be present for denormalization purposes (reporting).

Comment: I understand you set up this clear example for the sake of simplicity. I was just puzzled by these two definitions, with different semantics, of EntityA.EntityC, one in mapping and one in code, and was wondering about the expected behaviour of the proxy class. Maybe you can shed some light on this as it seems to be the core of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests with this class hierarchy and mapping on NH 3.3.3 SP1, and this is my observations:

- Load EntityA using `session.Get<>`, then do something with the object
  without touching the properties EntityB, EntityC, EntityB will
  not be loaded. Touching either property will trigger a query for
  sure, and this is normal.
- Load EntityA, updating something not related to the properties
  EntityB and EntityC like changing EntityA name, then rollback the
  transaction, no additional SELECT issued.
- Load EntityA, do nothing then commit the transaction, a second SELECT
  for the EntityB was issued.
- Load EntityA, do some querying with the session, then the said SELECT
  for EntityB was issued.

All tests are done under FlushMode.Auto.

From these, I reached the conclusion that the behaviour of NHibernate in this situation is totally expected: when doing a flush, NH need to check for object dirtiness, it needs to get the value of property EntityC to compare with the previous value, and this is what triggered the SELECT in question.

It definitely not because of `session.Get<>` or new Proxy. You can easily do more tests to prove this. I don't understand why NH 2.1.2 can be any different, though.

I also tried the tests on NH 3.3.1, the response was exactly the same with NH 3.3.3 SP1.

Comment: Thank you for the input - my test case falls into the "Load EntityA, do nothing, then commit the transaction..." case you mentioned above. Now, your conclusion made sense - so let's consider my updated mapping above where I have the EntityA -> EntityC relationship mapped with: insert="true" update="false" - would this not eliminate the dirty check required on flush?

Comment: Just tested. NH Profiler shows that the second SELECT is still issued. It seems that you will need different arrangement in classes and property, or override the dirty check of NHibernate to avoid that SELECT.